# Android : Difference between action id and fragment id in navigation component

Tags: android, navigation-architecture

I have a question that is bugging me for a long time,

In navigation component, when using .navigate(int resId) what makes a difference in passing an action id vs fragment id?

example:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
          android:name="com.example.myapp.ui.main.LoginFragment"
          android:label="@string/login"
          tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" >

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_login_to_emailLoginFragment"
        app:destination="@id/emailLoginFragment"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/emailLoginFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>

</fragment>

<fragment android:id="@+id/emailLoginFragment"
          android:name="com.example.myapp.ui.main.EmailLoginFragment"
          android:label="EmailLoginFragment"
          tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login_email" />
```

In the above scenario, what will be the difference if

1) use .navigate(R.id.action_login_to_emailLoginFragment);

2) use .navigate(R.id.emailLoginFragment);

And i have one more query, I know that .navigate(int resId) will replace the fragment, in that case how to retain state of views in previous fragment?

Comment: You should only ask one question at a time, but to answer your second question: any Fragment on the back stack automatically has its state saved and restored (same as if your device was rotated and went through a configuration change, etc).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of the other attributes on an action - i.e., the `popEnterAnim`, `popExitAnim`, `popUpTo`, and `popUpToInclusive` are part of a [NavOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavOptions) object that is automatically applied when you use that action id.

Therefore when you use `navigate(R.id.emailLoginFragment)`, none of the other fields are applied: you won't pop anything off the back stack nor will any animations be applied. To duplicate what the action provides, you'd need to use the [`navigate(int, Bundle, NavOptions)` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#navigate(int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20androidx.navigation.NavOptions)), manually constructing the correct `NavOptions`.